# Zend Framework 1 - How to reset view data, but not session data in functional integrational tests?

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, integration-testing

I'm stugling trying to develop tests for ZF1 based project. The tests already have been developed before me, but I have discovered that they work improperly. Calling `$this->dispatch('/some-path')` in test executes an action of an controller, but view data gets not cleared between multiple `$this->dispatch()` calls. Under view data I mean data assigned through `$this->view->assign()` in controller action. I need only view data to be cleared in tests while session data should be preserved between `$this->dispatch()` calls. I have tried to extend `Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase::dispatch()` and to modify it:

```
public function dispatch($url = null)
{
    // Reset view data
    $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
    $viewRenderer->view = null;

    return parent::dispatch($url);
}
```

Now view data becomes reseted, but same problem become with response output, it become accumulated somethere and I get accumulated result from multiple controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is:

```
public function dispatch($url = null)
{
    // Reset previous response
    $this->resetResponse();
    $this->getResponse();

    // Reset view data
    $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
    $viewRenderer->view = null;

    return parent::dispatch($url);
}
```